# What's the most idiomatic substitute for Ruby's missing string#unshift?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to build a string from right to left. My first thought was to use `unshift`, but `String` class doesn't have an `unshift`. What's the most idiomatic way to build a string from right to left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there's no `String#unshift`, there is a [`String#prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-prepend), which would allow you to prepend strings to an existing string.

```
str = "right"
str.prepend("middle ")
str.prepend("left ")

# left middle right
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Michael's answer. Here's another alternative: build an array of substrings from right to left, then call `Array#join` on it. If you have many substrings, this approach is likely to be faster than the `String#prepend` approach.